# Passing Node in the LinkedList doesn't print anything

Tags: java, linked-list

I pass `head` as a parameter in my `add()` method. I'm  calling the `add()` method in `public static void main(String args[])`. It doesn't print anything. But, if I don't pass `head` as a parameter, then it prints the linked list. Why is this happening?

Code that is not printing anything:

```
 public class linkedListI {
        static Node head;
    
        static class Node {
            int data;
            Node next;
    
            Node(int data) {
                this.data = data;
            }
        }
    
        static void add(Node head, int data) {
            Node new_node = new Node(data);
    
            if (head == null) {
    
                head = new_node;
                head.next = null;
            }
            Node current = head;
            while (current.next != null) {
                current = current.next;
            }
            current.next = new_node;
            new_node.next = null;
    
        }
    
        static void printLinkedList(Node head) {
            Node curr = head;
            while (curr != null) {
                System.out.print(curr.data + " ");
                curr = curr.next;
            }
        }
    
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            // linkedListI l = new linkedListI();
            add(head, 3);
            add(head, 4);
            add(head, 6);
            add(head, 7);
            printLinkedList(head);
        }
    }
```

Code that gives the output:

This code prints the output but I am not passing `head` as a parameter in the `add()` method.

```
public class linkedListI {
    static Node head;

    static class Node {
        int data;
        Node next;

        Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    static void add(int data) {
        Node new_node = new Node(data);

        if (head == null) {

            head = new_node;
            head.next = null;
        }
        Node current = head;
        while (current.next != null) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        current.next = new_node;
        new_node.next = null;

    }

    static void printLinkedList(Node head) {
        Node curr = head;
        while (curr != null) {
            System.out.print(curr.data + " ");
            curr = curr.next;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // linkedListI l = new linkedListI();
        add(3);
        add(4);
        add(6);
        add(7);
        printLinkedList(head);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that in your first version, you have:

```
static void add(Node head, int data)
```

This means that any reference to `head` in this function will be the local variable, not the class member that is defined at the very top of your script.

As the parameter is a *local* variable, when you assign a new value to it, no-one will know about it, only the function's execution context. The calling code will see no change in `head`, because arguments are passed by value. So `head` will remain `null` after every call to `add`.

If you want it to work that way -- passing a `head` as argument -- then change the signature of your `add` function, so that it returns the final value of `head` back to the caller, who must then reassign it back to its own `head` variable:

```
    static void add(Node head, int data) {
        Node new_node = new Node(data);

        new_node.next = null;
        if (head == null) {
            return new_node; // this is the new head
        }
        Node current = head;
        while (current.next != null) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        current.next = new_node;
        return head; // head did not change
    }

// ....

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        head = add(head, 3);
        head = add(head, 4);
        head = add(head, 6);
        head = add(head, 7);
        printLinkedList(head);
    }
```

Comment: Just a query but the local variable isn't defined with static keyword here I have made head as static.

Comment: Yes, and what is your query?